# In France, 1916, would a soldier who was invalided out of the army, e.g. as an amputee, still get his army pay?

Tags: military, france, world-war-one

In France, the law providing ex-servicemen with an army pension did not come in until 1919, so if wounded soldiers were unable to fight, what did they live on?

Comment: Generally speaking (i.e. not specifically looking at France in 1916), if you are unfit to continue serving, you are dismissed from the military as "disabled", and have to go on living a civilian life. You may, or may not, get a stipend, or help for reintegrating into general society. The French term for such disabled veterans is [invalide de guerre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invalide_de_guerre).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a partial answer.

[Petite et Grande histoire du CPMIVG](https://code.pensionsmilitaires.com/histoire-cpmivg) says that the 1919 law wasn't the first law passed in France, nor the last.

> Si ces deux droits à « Reconnaissance » et « Réparation » – qui sont toujours, aujourd’hui, les piliers porteurs du Code des pensions militaires d’invalidité et des victimes de guerre – n’avaient cessé d’évoluer depuis François 1er, avec quelques dates jalons plus ou moins connues (édit de Louis XIV du 24 février 1670 emportant construction des Invalides à Paris, loi du 2 août de l’assemblée constituante et décret du 22 août 1790, lois des 11 et 18 avril 1831), c’est bien la violence de cette première guerre mondiale qui est à l’origine de la construction d’un véritable système organisé autour de la « Dette » de la Nation, d’abord envers ceux qui ont été atteints dans leur chair ou leur vie parce qu’ils portaient ses armes (militaires et assimilés) mais également envers ses victimes civiles (de guerre et aujourd’hui du terrorisme), sans oublier les familles des uns et des autres.

---

And you might find this description relevant: [Les blessés de la grande guerre](https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2016/12/29/2487349-les-blesses-de-la-grande-guerre.html). It ends with,

> L'entraide associative entre blessés, déjà existante pendant le conflit, connaît une très forte dynamique dans l'après-guerre. Unions d'anciens combattants, d'aide aux blessés, de gueules cassées, sont très présentes sur le terrain public et politique pour faire entendre leurs revendications. Compensation financière, réparation des dommages subies, plein emploi, et acquisition d'un appareillage adapté constituent leurs principales doléances.
>
> L'État français, redevable envers ces hommes sacrifiés, tente alors de suppléer à leurs difficultés. Dès 1916, une loi institue des «emplois réservés» dans les administrations pour les militaires réformés pour infirmités contractées pendant la guerre. La même année, l'Office national des mutilés et réformés de guerre est mis sur pied. Dédié à leur réinsertion professionnelle, il subventionne des centres de rééducation tournés vers l'apprentissage de métiers artisanaux ou agricoles. En 1919, ils obtiennent une pension d'invalidité. L'Office, prémice de l'actuel ONAC, n'aura dès lors de cesse de rendre hommage et de reconnaître l'engagement, le sacrifice, la souffrance de ces milliers de soldats qui ont combattu pour la liberté de la France.

In summary, care was provided by the State and supplemented by local help (from the communes i.e. mayors), organisations like the red cross, and individuals who  volunteered labour, goods, and dwellings; the wounded were housed in hospitals but also schools, chateaux, village halls, nunneries; and they'd typically have their own families too.

From 1916 there were jobs reserved for invalids who were able to work (I can only presume that invalids who weren't able to work were cared for).

---

There are further details here: [À l’origine de la réinsertion professionnelle des personnes handicapées : la prise en charge des invalides de guerre](https://www.cairn.info/revue-francaise-des-affaires-sociales-2005-2-page-229.htm)

> La situation du marché du travail invitait également à privilégier l’insertion professionnelle à l’assistance. Pendant la guerre, la pénurie d’hommes rendait indispensable la réintégration des mutilés, soit au front, soit à l’arrière, dans les plus brefs délais. La mise en application par l’État du triptyque – rééducation fonctionnelle, rééducation professionnelle et réemploi – dans l’hôpital militaire du Grand Palais et dans les asiles Vacassy et de Saint-Maurice répondait à cet objectif. Beaucoup de mutilés se réadaptent ainsi ; d’autres, plus nombreux encore, se familiarisent avec une nouvelle profession dans les ateliers des industriels qui acceptent d’assurer cette formation. Mais avec la fin du conflit, l’insertion sociale des mutilés de guerre devient plus difficile. Le retour progressif des millions de démobilisés détend le marché du travail et met en concurrence une main-d’œuvre valide avec les mutilés.

So during the war there was a shortage of man-power: and opportunity, demand, for retraining and work. It was after the end of the war that the job market became more difficult, flooded with people returning from the war, and employers were less enthusiastic about hiring the wounded.

Also a law passed in 1916 created some reserved jobs in the public-sector:

> La loi du 17 avril 1916, s’inscrivait dans cette démarche. Celle-ci instituait, aux anciens militaires réformés ou retraités par suite de blessures ou d’infirmités contractées durant la guerre, des « emplois réservés » dans les administrations publiques. Cette loi a été complétée par les lois des 30 janvier 1923 et 21 juillet 1928, puis étendue par la loi du 26 octobre 1946 aux victimes civiles de la guerre de 1939-1945 et élargie aux entreprises nationalisées par la loi du 19 août 1950.